# P value adjustment for pairwise comparisons of negative binomial

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, lsmeans, glmmtmb, multiplicity

Question 1) Am I appropriately doing the pairwise comparisons?

Question 2) Why is the Sidak method used for the emmeans? Should I instead use adjust = "none" for these?

Context:
I have a negative binomial looking at the effect of three treatments on count data:

```
M1a <- glmmTMB(data = A, n ~ Treatment, family = nbinom2, ziformula = ~0)
```

I'd like to compare the means of each treatment with one another:

```
emmeans(M1a, pairwise ~ Treatment, adjust = "tukey", type = "response")
```

This produces the following output:

```
$emmeans
 Treatment response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 C             9.96 1.56 14     6.51     15.2
 E             9.31 1.46 14     6.08     14.2
 A             6.78 1.08 14     4.41     10.4

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: sidak method for 3 estimates 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 

$contrasts
 contrast ratio    SE df t.ratio p.value
 C / E     1.07 0.237 14 0.304   0.9505 
 C / A     1.47 0.328 14 1.726   0.2305 
 E / A     1.37 0.307 14 1.422   0.3568 

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
Tests are performed on the log scale
```

I was using the Tukey adjustment as that's what I understood the emmeans vignette on "confidence-intervals" to be recommending. I assume this is correcting for two probability distributions (eg. treatment "C" and treatment "E").
I notice though that after the means estimation table it says the Sidak method was used for CI adjustment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking for two things -- means and pairwise differences. The Tukey adjustment is appropriate only for the latter, so it substitutes Sidak for the means. If you leave out the adjust argument altogether, it will default to "none" and "tukey" respectively.

I highly recommend not using two-sided formulas for this kind of reason, unless you are willing to go with default options. When you have options that could apply to either set of estimates, it's hard to know which set they will apply to.

To do it in two steps (illustrated applying a non-default adjustment to the comparisons):

```
emm <- emmeans(M1a, ~ Treatment, type = "response")
emm
pairs(emm, adjust = "mvt")
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you Russ. The default will do what I am after then.
With regard to the single-sided formula, I can get the means by simply removing the "pairwise" ie: emmeans(M1a, ~ Treatment, type = "response"). How do I just get the pairwise differences?

Comment: I added to the answer. There are several vignettes in the package, with lots of examples.